# java fx vbox IndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: javafx, indexoutofboundsexception, scenebuilder, gluon

Hey guys ım a newbie in java fx. My code changes
labels design with the output of the rand func(1-16).
Initially my code works without an error but I want my design 
auto-resizing responsive page, so I put my 16 label in a Vbox
and it is now a responsive page. Problem starst here. I do not
figure it out how to access a vbox by code. My code cant access 
labels and it give errors. When I put my labels out of vbox code
is working again. I am wondering that the using vbox is okey ?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
int myrand = rand.nextInt(15)+1;
System.out.println(myrand + "blue");
root.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(myrand).setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
```

However; the code points this line without any error sign on the row numbers.

```
root.getChildrenUnmodifiable().get(myrand).setStyle("-fx-background-color: blue");
```

Here is the full error log

```
Exception in thread "Timer-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 10, Size: 2
10blue
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:653)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:429)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.ObservableListWrapper.get(ObservableListWrapper.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.get(VetoableListDecorator.java:306)
    at javafx.collections.FXCollections$UnmodifiableObservableListImpl.get(FXCollections.java:936)
    at javafxapp.Lighproject$1.run(Lighproject.java:42)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

As you see it work with 1 loop and give the error. And this is my Hierarchy
[gluon scene builder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gN7ln.png)
Eror belongs top Vbox.

Comment: Give the `labels` an `FX:ID`.

Comment: If you are going to be changing all the labels using the same style, give the `VBox` an `FX:ID` and get its children.

Comment: alread gave an id of the every node

Comment: Seems like you need to do some basic JavaFX FXML tutorials.

Comment: Apperently its is a thread issue. But do not know hot to change the code :)

Comment: You said you gave an fx:id to all nodes. Use the GridPanes fx:id to get its children.

Comment: sohuld ı use grid pane instead of vbox ?

Comment: Sorry I meant use the VBox fx:id to get its children.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `int myrand = rand.nextInt(root.getChildren().size());`.

This is happening because your `myrand` variable is bigger than how many nodes are in the `root` group.